# Cannot load my JSON file: Http failure during parsing for JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am attempting to load valid json but I am getting the error:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/amh-angular-recipes)

> Http failure during parsing for ... .json

[image]

**recipe.component.ts**

```
 url = '../../files/recipes.json';
  recipes;

  constructor(private fileService: FileLoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileService.getData(this.url).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

**file-loader.service.ts**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

Comment: You can't load files with a relative URL like that. Best bet would be to put the JSON in your /assets/ folder and use that as your url.

Comment: If I were doing it via CLI and not on the stackblitz, I'd have done it that way. Just wasn't sure why I couldn't.

Comment: Even doing that isn't working? `url = '/assets/recipes.json';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not a valid JSON file.  epascarello's answer tells you how to convert it to valid JSON, but another option is to just import the data directly.

1. Change the `.json` file extension to `.ts`
2. In your component, add `import {recipes} from '../../files/recipes'`
3. You've got your data!  No need to mess around with http requests.

Answer (score 2):

Having the export

```
export const recipes = [
  {...}
]
```

makes it not a valid json document. Do not use export, remove it

JSON file should just be the json.

```
[
  {...}
]
```

Comment: Whoops. Forgot I'd left that in when I converted it back from .ts. Mustn't have saved it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple this wrong and missing here:

1. This is not a valid JSON file (in the stackblitz). This is a constant which you can just import using a normal typescript import. If you want to load it using http, you should remove the `export const recipes` from the file
2. You should move the files folder to the assets folder of the project, this way the file can be loaded from the http server.

Answer (score -1):

I spent a while ripping my hair out today (new to writing in StackBlitz). and even tried what was marked as answer on this thread, with no luck. Anyhow, the key seemed to be adding the .json file to the assets folder. Here's the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) that finally got me immediate success. Hope that helps someone else keep their hair in tact. :-)

I've been asked to add code snippet, but not really too much to add, so I created a StackBlitz example that can be viewed, if desired. However, basically it all boils down to this: in ***StackBlitz*** when you're loading a local .json file, you do the same thing you normally would...except you ABSOLUTELY put that .json file in the "assets" folder (if you don't have one, create one)

```
   this.http.get('/assets/user.json')
```

I added a StackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bfinney-so52635100?embed=1&file=src/app/data.service.ts&view=editor)

Comment: please add an example section for the code linked - otherwise this answer may be downvoted on quality